# Why do I keep getting an empty list when using re.findall()?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
fhand = open("regex_sum_196551.txt")

lst=list()
regex = '[0-9]+'

#iterate through each line
for line in fhand:
    #strip default whitespace charachters from the ends of the line
    line=line.rstrip()
    #look for all integers that match the regex in the line and add to the list
    lst = re.findall(regex,line)

print(lst)
```

Hi, I'm trying to work my way through this. I don't need the answer, but just some context as to why the last is always empty. Am I using the re.findall() incorrectly?

Comment: Immediately you're redefining `lst` each line without saving the results. Perhaps you mean something like `lst = re.findall(regex, fhand.read())` without a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last line on your file doesn't contain any number. Since you print out the `lst` after loop, your `lst` variable will assigned by the value of `re.findall` on the last line. If the last line desn't contain any number, then `findall` method will return empty list. You can print out the `lst` at the end of for loop:

```
#iterate through each line
for line in fhand:
    #strip default whitespace charachters from the ends of the line
    line=line.rstrip()
    #look for all integers that match the regex in the line and add to the list
    lst = re.findall(regex,line)
    print(lst)
```

or extend the list as @wpercy answer.